# How to use async method in Flutter Focus onKeyEvent

Tags: android, flutter

I have a Flutter app targeting Android TV devices (as well as phones), so I had to implement some special logic to handle the remote.

I wrapped buttons that need to be clicked by a remote with a `Focus` widget:

```
 Widget myButton(BuildContext context) {
   Focus(
        onKeyEvent: (node, event) {
          return manageKeyboard(event, context);
        },
          child: IconButton(
      // ... button properties here
    ),
  );
}
```

I wrote `manageKeyboard` method like this:

```
 KeyEventResult manageKeyboard(KeyEvent event, BuildContext context) {
    if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowRight) {
      if (event is KeyUpEvent) {
        doSomething(context, true);
      }
      return KeyEventResult.handled;
    }
 }
```

This works reasonably well. Problem is if I try to make `managedKeyboard` asynchrounous in order to await `doSomething`, I get below error in `onKeyEvent`:

```
The argument type 'Future<KeyEventResult> Function(FocusNode, KeyEvent)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'KeyEventResult Function(FocusNode, KeyEvent)?'.
```

How can I make `onKeyEvent` asynchrounous?

Answer (score 2):

You cant assign a future callback to 'onKeyEvent'.

Instead, You may register a callback to 'manageKeyboard' as follows,

```
            onKeyEvent: (node, event) {
              manageKeyboard(event, context).then((value) {
                print(value);
              });
              return KeyEventResult.ignored;
            },
```

And keep 'manageKeyboard' method as follows,

```
  Future<KeyEventResult> manageKeyboard(KeyEvent event, BuildContext context) async {
    if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowRight) {
      if (event is KeyUpEvent) {
        await doSomething();
        return KeyEventResult.handled;
      }
    }
 return KeyEventResult.ignored;
}
```

Comment: `manageKeyboard ` method returns either handled or ignored. The new code always returns ignored. Also, my understanding is that manageKeyboard is not going to be awaited, so ignored will be returned immediately while manageKeyboard is still executing? I want to await manageKeyboard and use its return value

Answer (score 2):

> According to the Focus Widget [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Focus/onKeyEvent.html), You can do this by onKey property with the async function.

```
Focus(
  onKey: (FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) async {
    if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowRight) {
      await doSomething();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  child: Container()
)
```

Comment: This is from documentation for that property: "This is a legacy API based on RawKeyEvent and will be deprecated in the future. Prefer onKeyEvent instead." (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Focus/onKey.html)